# What's the Grammar Form at Work Here and How to Use it? 「あまり難しく考えるなよ」

Tags: grammar, verbs, adjectives, i-adjectives

Looking at the Japanese lines of a game, and I came across this line...:

> あまり難しく考えるなよ。

...which I believe translates to "Don't think about it too much" or the like. However, I don't understand what's going on here exactly, grouping the く-form of an い-adjective and a verb like that. The only other place I've seen something like this so far is with the く-form of an い-adjective + なる, but I'm still curious how it's being used above.

So, in short, how does this work and can it be used accordingly with other adjectives and verbs?

Comment: Check out this Q&A: (possible dupe) https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/26093

Comment: @A.Ellett the な just adds a conjugation to the verb. The adjective in question is still just the adverbial form, as explained in the linked question. I see no grammatical difference here...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, 難しく and 考える are grouped here. The ku-form is a form used to modify a verb, in other words, it works like an adverb. See [this article](https://www.tofugu.com/japanese-grammar/i-adjective-ku-form/), too.

- 速く走る to run fast
- よく考える to think hard
- 弱く叩く to hit/tap lightly
- 格好良く踊る to dance in a cool manner

Likewise, 難しく考える means "to think in a difficult/complicated way".